# Algorithmic efficiency of rotating a point

Tags: computational-complexity, rotations

I am trying to calculate the algorithmic effciency (Big-O) of rotating **n** 3-D vertices using the rotation matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & cos(a) & -sin(a) \\ 0 & sin(a) & cos(a)\end{bmatrix}$ 
$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$

I am kind of new to Big-O and have no idea where to start. I am tempted to say **O(9n)** but the computation requires addition and multiplication so it seems naive. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't multiplication by a $3\times 3$ matrix of constant complexity?  We do not ordinarily include a constant factor $9$ when describing complexity because $O(9n)$ is the same as $O(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a little searching for 2 matrices (one vertex), one **s * m** and **m * p**, the compuational complexity is evaluated at **O(smp)** or **O(3 * 3 * 1)** = **O(9)**. It makes sense I guess

Comment: So for n vertices it would just be $\mathcal{O}(n)$?